# Most optimal way to check specific characters only appear in a string

Tags: c#, string, .net-core-3.0

**Goal:** Return a boolean whether any of the passed characters is not in a string. While looping through the string, if any character that was passed is contained in string index, continue, else return false.

I have a working solution below, however, *performance is very important to me.*

**Assumptions:**

- Could be any string of any length.
- Case is important

Is there a more optimal solution?

My current code and expected test cases.

```cs
    public static bool ContainsOnlyChars(string strValue, params char[] charValues)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("String cannot be null or empty.");

            for (int i = 0; i < strValue.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!charValues.Any(c=> c == strValue[i]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Test cases would look like this, I have lots, but here is a few.

```cs
// should return true
Console.WriteLine(ContainsOnlyChars("\n", '\n'));
Console.WriteLine(ContainsOnlyChars("\n\n", '\n'));
Console.WriteLine(ContainsOnlyChars("\n\n ", '\n', ' '));
Console.WriteLine(ContainsOnlyChars("ab", 'a', 'b'));

Console.WriteLine();

// should return false
Console.WriteLine(ContainsOnlyChars("\nz", '\n')); // because of z
Console.WriteLine(ContainsOnlyChars("z\n\n", '\n')); // because of z
Console.WriteLine(ContainsOnlyChars("\n\n z", '\n', ' ')); // because of z
Console.WriteLine(ContainsOnlyChars("abz", 'a', 'b')); // because of z
```

Actual Test Cases which are slightly different, only take in string and fixed character array.
https://pastebin.com/xS0sRC4n

Comment: `return strValue.All(charValues.Contains);` But your code looks fine. Is it not working?

Comment: This is not different from the OP in terms of running time cost

Comment: What performance issue are you seeing? I don't think it gets any better than what you have.

Comment: @RufusL I'm simply putting this out there if any micro optimizations exists? For this requirement, this function will be called many, many times, so any optimization *if any* is appreciated. The post is merely to see if one may exist.

Comment: You could use a `Hashset` or a `BitArray` with 65536 elements for a faster lookup. The best solution will depend on how many charValues you have.

Comment: Your tests are inconsistent with your implementation. `ContainsOnlyChars("abc", 'a')` returns false, although you claim that *should return true* because *because 'a' does appear*. It seems that your question is ambiguous about what you are trying to do. Are you searching for the existence of invalid characters in the string?

Comment: Do you care about other languages? Is `==` really what you want or do you want a culture sensitive comparison that understands that `ß` (Eszett) can also be written `ss`?

Comment: Updated OP to best reflect my intent. The test cases I wrote up for this post were incorrect, my original test cases in pastebin still hold.

Answer (score 2):

Your current solution is O(MN), create a lookup of your stringvalues and check against that.

```
public static bool ContainsOnlyChars(string strValue, params char[] charValues)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("String cannot be null or empty.");

    var chrLookup = charValues.ToLookup(c => c);

    for (int i = 0; i < strValue.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!chrLookup.Contains(strValue[i]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202122/discussion-on-answer-by-johanp-most-optimal-way-to-check-specific-characters-onl).

Answer (score 1):

Checking two lists with each other is a task of `O(n * m)` where n and m are sizes of the list. But if you both of them are long enough you can use `HashSets` to locate items of the other in it.

In your case you can create a dictionary from your original string with time `O(n)` then check each of the other items to exist in that dictionary with time `O(m)` making it an `O(n + m)` algorithm

```
public static bool ContainsOnlyChars(string strValue, params char[] charValues)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("String cannot be null or empty.");

    // The O(n) part
    var dic = new Dictionary<char, bool>();
    foreach (var ch in strValue)
        if (!dic.ContainsKey(ch))
            dic.Add(ch,1);

    // The O(m) part
    foreach (var ch in charValues)
        if(!dic.ContainsKey(ch))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Disclaimer: I have written the code in browser.

Comment: Assuming the `1` is true in the line `dic.Add(ch, 1)`, the resulting function does not work with my original unit tests, in fact when it should return true, it returns false.

Comment: Using a `Hashset` would be simpler.

Comment: The answer of Johan is better. I decided not to change this one though. Follow his.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to consider would be:

```
public static bool ContainsOnlyChars(string strValue, params char[] charValues)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("String cannot be null or empty.");

    return !strValue.Except(charValues).Any();
}
```

Basically the code returns `false` if there are any characters in `strValue` that aren't in `charValues`.